# How to split string into column names with python/panda?

Tags: python, pandas

Do you know how to solve this in python? I would like to have a dataframe with data arranged in the correct column.

Thanks in advance!

Here is an example of a string from a dataframe.

' Huidigefuncties Michael Jordan 2015 - present Director Marketing & Indirect Channels, Ricoh Nederland 2010 - present Basketball Center, Center for Business-Expertise Loopbaan Michael Jordan 2012 - 2015 Director Marketing & Business Development, Ricoh Opleiding Michael Jordan 1988 - 1992 Marketing , Harvard '

Preferred result

```
type          from     to        function                                   organization           
current       2015     present    Director Marketing & Indirect Channels    Ricoh Nederland 
current       2010     present    Owner & Consultant                        Basketball Center
old           2012     2015       Director Marketing & Business Development Ricoh
school        1988     1992       Marketing                                 Harvard
```

Current df

```
Name             Data
Michael Jordan   ' Huidigefuncties Michael Jordan 2015 - present Director Marketing & Indirect Channels, Ricoh Nederland 2010 - present Basketball Center, Center for Business-Expertise Loopbaan Michael Jordan 2012 - 2015 Director Marketing & Business Development, Ricoh Opleiding Michael Jordan 1988 - 1992 Marketing , Harvard '
```

Comment: Where are you getting the column `type` ?

Comment: Huidigefunctie = current
Loopbaan = old
Opleiding = school

Comment: Are you reading for a csv with header? are you file multiline ?

Comment: No it's not a csv. it from beautifulsoup.

Comment: Are you sharing the right data ? the `owner & consultant` function is not in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a solution that I did for this problem

```
import pandas as pd
beautiful_data = 'Huidigefuncties Michael Jordan 2015 - present Director Marketing & Indirect Channels, Ricoh Nederland 2010 - present Basketball Center, Center for Business-Expertise Loopbaan Michael Jordan 2012 - 2015 Director Marketing & Business Development, Ricoh Opleiding Michael Jordan 1988 - 1992 Marketing , Harvard'
main_dict = {'type':[], 'from':[], 'to':[], 'function':[], 'organization': []}
data = beautiful_data.split(' ')
i = 0
huidi_index = data.index('Huidigefuncties')
loopbaan_index = data.index('Loopbaan')
ople_index = data.index('Opleiding')
# print(data)
while i < len(data):
    if data[i] == 'Huidigefuncties':
        line = ' '.join(data[i + 1: loopbaan_index])
        i = loopbaan_index
        print(line)
        type_data = 'current'
    elif data[i] == 'Loopbaan':
        line = ' '.join(data[i + 1: ople_index])
        i = ople_index
        print(line)
        type_data = 'old'
    elif data[i] == 'Opleiding':
        line = ' '.join(data[i+1: ])
        i = len(data)
        print(line)
        type_data = 'school'
    else:
        i += 1
    data_line = line.split('-')
    if len(data_line) == 2:
        print(type_data)
        main_dict['type'].append(type_data)
        from_data = data_line[0].strip().split(' ')[-1]
        print(from_data)
        main_dict['from'].append(from_data)
        to_data = data_line[1].strip().split(' ')[0]
        print(to_data)
        main_dict['to'].append(to_data)
        function_data = ' '.join(data_line[1].strip().split(' ')[1:-1])[:-1]
        print(function_data)
        main_dict['function'].append(function_data)
        organization_data = data_line[1].split(',')[-1].strip()
        print(organization_data)
        main_dict['organization'].append(organization_data)

    elif len(data_line) > 2:
        j = 0
        while j < len(data_line):
            register_data = data_line[j:j+2]
            if len(register_data) > 1:
                if len(register_data[0].split(' ')) > 1 and len(register_data[1].split(' ')) > 1: 
                    if j == 0:
                        print(register_data)
                        print('----------')
                        print(type_data)
                        main_dict['type'].append(type_data)
                        from_data = register_data[0].strip().split(' ')[-1]
                        print(from_data)
                        main_dict['from'].append(from_data)
                        to_data = register_data[1].strip().split(' ')[0]
                        print(to_data)
                        main_dict['to'].append(to_data)
                        function_org = register_data[1].strip().split(',')
                        function_data = ' '.join(function_org[0].split(' ')[1:])
                        print(function_data)
                        main_dict['function'].append(function_data)
                        org_data = ' '.join(function_org[1].split(' ')[:-1]).strip()
                        print(org_data)
                        main_dict['organization'].append(org_data)
                        print('-----------')
                    else:
                        print('-----------')
                        print(register_data)
                        print(type_data)
                        main_dict['type'].append(type_data)
                        from_data = register_data[0].strip().split(' ')[-1]
                        print(from_data)
                        main_dict['from'].append(from_data)
                        to_data = register_data[1].strip().split(' ')[0]
                        print(to_data)
                        main_dict['to'].append(to_data)
                        function_org = register_data[1].strip().split(',')
                        function_data = ' '.join(function_org[0].split(' ')[1:])
                        print(function_data)
                        main_dict['function'].append(function_data)
                        org_data = ' '.join(function_org[1].split(' ')).strip()
                        print(org_data)
                        main_dict['organization'].append(org_data)
                        print('-----------')
            j += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(main_dict)
```

Tested

[image]